# Log transformation to generate random number producing NA's

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to generate a random values using log distribution. The reason for using log-distribution is keep the values positive.

```
    #generating 50,000 K values with a mean and CV of 20% 

    cv=0.2 # 20% cv for the values of Ke, rro and used in the simulation 

    calc_sd <- function(mean,cv){
      sd=mean*cv
      print(sd)
    }

    mu<-(6.19*10^-3)
    sd <-(0.001238)

    #generating 50,000 samples and will randomly sample 1000 from these 
nsample <- 50000    
kdist <- data.frame(id=1:nsample)
    kdist$KE <- exp(rnorm(nsample, mean=log(mu),sd=log(sd)))

    exp(mean(log(kdist$KE)))
exp(sd(log(kdist$KE)))

    Warning message:
    In rnorm(nsample, mean = log(mu), sd = log(sd)) : NAs produced
```

This is the warning message I keep getting

My question is how do I adderss this issue. I ave tried using one of the previous suggestions which was mentioned here and it does not work.

https://msalganik.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/making-sense-of-the-rlnorm-function-in-r/

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Is-my-understanding-of-rlnorm-correct-td853068.html

My second question is : is there a way to directly use CV instead of sd for the generating this ?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Got the solution after reprametrization as suggested by this link

https://msalganik.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/making-sense-of-the-rlnorm-function-in-r/

Comment: Check log(0.001238) to see what can you get. Then check the requirement of SD.

Comment: > log(0.001238)
[1] -6.694258   Thanks for the response. What do you mean by requirements ? @user158565

Comment: SD > 0. If SD<0, rnorm does not work.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you please suggest a way to work around this ? Is there any simple trick ?

Comment: I do not know what you want to do, i.e., why use log(SD)?

Comment: The I am trying to generate 50000 samples using a mean and sd. The reason for using log transformed values is to keep the random values which are generated positive.                                                                            
 kedist$KE1<-rlnorm(nsample,meanlog=log
                   (mu),sdlog=abs(log(sd)))

exp(mean(log(kedist$KE1)))

exp(sd(log(kedist$KE1)))   when I try using the absolute value the expected sd for the output is not what it should be

Comment: You can use `rlnorm` to generate samples from a log-normal distribution. If you want mu and sd to be the mean and standard deviation of the lognormal distribution you don't have to take the log : > rlnorm(nsample, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sd)

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try the expected mean and sd are not the same\. Example: mu<-(6.19*10^-3)
sd <-(0.001238)                                                                                             
 kedist <- data.frame(id=1:nsample)

kedist$KE1<-rlnorm(nsample,meanlog=
                   (mu),sdlog=sd)
kedist$KE1<-rlnorm(nsample,meanlog=
                   log(mu),sdlog=(sd))

(mean((kedist$KE1)))

(sd(log(kedist$KE1)))

Comment: i got the solutions. https://msalganik.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/making-sense-of-the-rlnorm-function-in-r/ this is a good reference

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to simulate draws from a lognormal distribution. (The phrase "log distribution" or "log-distribution" has no definite meaning that I know of.)

I am treating this as a statistical question -- not one about your R code -- because the root problem is statistical misunderstanding.

Your code seems transparent as a summary of your goal:

`exp(rnorm(nsample, mean=log(mu),sd=log(sd)))`

The fallacy here is that a lognormal with mean $\mu$ and SD $\sigma$ corresponds to a normal with mean log $\mu$ and SD log $\sigma$. Not so; and taking the absolute value if either logarithm is negative can't rescue you from absolute error.

As pointed out in comments, the SD of a normal (or indeed any distribution) can't be negative.

The relationships between the mean and SD of a normal and the mean and SD of the corresponding lognormal are well defined: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution is a good source.

However, you should not need those relationships. I would be amazed if there weren't several good ways of drawing from a lognormal in R, but what is best or even good in R is off-topic here and beyond my expertise in any case.

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand that the sd cannot be -ve as it is the square root of variance in theory. and the sqrt of any number cannot be negative. However, after trying to find several ways to get the exact mean and sd https://msalganik.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/making-sense-of-the-rlnorm-function-in-r/ This link is my best guess to work using rlnorm function in r.